# Hide Currency Records from User

Tags: user, currency

I have one new user in our Salesforce org that we only want to see records with the ZAR (south africa) currency. Our org has multi-currencies enabled (our business trades in USD and AUD), but we only want our new user to be able to see records with the ZAR currency. How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do that. There's a very robust sharing model in Salesforce, but there's no such setting as "show users only records in a specific currency." You could set all objects to private, and then create some Criteria-Based Sharing rules, which would be the closest approximation, but it's probably better if you just use the Role Hierarchy and/or Territory Management to manage those shares. See the documentation for [Role Hierarchy Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.security_controlling_access_using_hierarchies.htm&type=5) and [Territory Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.tm2_territory_mgmt_overview.htm&type=5) to figure out if one of these solutions may work for you.